# grunt-bower-task throws "Warning: Cannot find module 'bower' Use --force to continue."

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower

When doing `grunt bower:install` grunt throws the following error

```
kaushiks-MacBook-Pro:ama ghost$ grunt bower:install
Running "bower:install" (bower) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'bower' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
kaushiks-MacBook-Pro:ama ghost$
```

I have tried `npm install bower -g` but still din't work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need Bower as a local dependency and not global. If you are using [`grunt-bower-task`](https://github.com/yatskevich/grunt-bower-task) you should've downloaded Bower from its dependencies already - but since the error specifically says that it cannot find module `bower` you should install it locally in your project's root with `npm install bower -D`.

The `-D` option is shorthand for `--save-dev` which only installs the dependency if `NODE_ENV` environment variable is `development`, which it is by default.